# What permissions are considered special in the Play Store?

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play

I have added the following **permissions** onto my app:

> full network access
>
> view network connections

When installing the app the Play Store says: **"APP_NAME does not require any special permissions"**. I assume that the two permissions are not considered special.

However they are listed in the permissions section of the app webpage on the store website. They fall under the "other" category.

How may we know which permissions are not considered special if we want to avoid adding them to the app? Is there a list anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [Review App Permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972)

> Google Play prioritizes the permissions that are most important for
>   you to make an informed decision, displaying them front and center.

A concise idea about it has been described on this blog about the [Permission Groups change](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/27n7yr/what_latest_changes_to_play_store_app_means_for/).

Welcome to StackOverflow, do try to post (almost only) code related questions here. Refer [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to read more on why code related Qs.